# Insert Command error

Tags: sql

I wanna write insert command in sql 2005.
I have 10 Columns, some of them can be null.
I use this command:
Insert Into TableName Values(x,y)
since the others can be null, I don't bring them in command.
cause, number of null-able columns are different, I can't bring exact null values.
but I've got this error:Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
what can I do?

Comment: Have you try to specify the column name ? INSERT INTO Store_Information (store_name, Sales, Date)
VALUES ('Los Angeles', 900, 'Jan-10-1999')

Answer (score 5):

1 - **Accept some of the past answers to your questions.**

2 - Supply which fields you are inserting.  In a 5 column table, you can say

```
INSERT INTO Table (col2, col4)
VALUES (col2value, col4value)
```

Comment: @User - then how do you expect to do an insert if you don't know how many values you have?